# Making sticky div up to a point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a div start being fixed when he gets to a certain div, and to stop being sticky when he hits another div, but stay in the position where he left. The position of the div where the sticky div should stop can be anywhere depending on the article lenght. I can get it to work on one resolution, but not so much on others.

Surprisingly, getting fixed works most of the time, but the "stop being fixed" part mostly doesn't work (my div just messes up in height).

Here is my code:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
   var topOfLastDiv = ($("#scroll_to").position().top)-630;
   var topOfFirstDiv = ($("#tour_user_info").position().top)+20;
   var topOfLastDivSocial = topOfLastDiv+100;
   var y = $(document).scrollTop(),
       header = $("#tour_price_map");
       social_media = $('#social_media_sticky');

   if (y < topOfFirstDiv) {
       header.css({position: "relative", "top" : "0px", "transform": "translateX(0)"});
       header.fadeIn(100);
       social_media.fadeOut(100);
   }
   if(y >= topOfFirstDiv && y<topOfLastDiv)  {
       social_media.fadeIn(100);
       header.css({position: "fixed", "top" : "50px", "transform": "translateX(216.2%)"});
   }
   if (y >= topOfLastDiv && y < topOfLastDivSocial) {
       header.css({position: "relative", "top" : topOfLastDiv-520, "transform": "translateX(0)"});
   }
   if (y>= topOfLastDivSocial) {
       social_media.fadeOut(100);
       header.css({position: "relative", "top" : topOfLastDiv-520, "transform": "translateX(0)"});
   }
});
```

The random numbers in code is me trying to make it fit on my laptops resolution which works great then.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with using "absolute" instead of "relative" in the last 2 if clauses and adjusted "top" and "transform" accordingly.